# Horizontal overflow hidden items display when clicking on page and dragging right

Tags: html, css, overflow

I display 2 graphics either side of my page content. When the browser/page width narrows these items are cropped off the screen to allow more room for the content. This is mainly

```
.page {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

That all works fine but I have a `min-width` set on the `.page` div which wraps around all the content and is the next element after the opening `body` tag. I've just realised that when the browser width goes below the `min-width` the vertical scroll bar disappears from the side of the page.

Here's a CodePen of the issue: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/oemBEN

Presumably that is because the `body` is now in view but the `.page` element remains at it's set `min-width` ...makes sense.

However, the reason I set the overflow on the `.page` element in the first place is because of an issue I was having when it was set on the `body`. An issue I thought I'd resolved by applying the code this way.

If I move the following code to the `body`:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

All appears to work as I'd like it to. The items either side of the content area are cropped and the vertical scroll bar remains in view when the content is long enough in Chrome + FireFox on Mac. If I check the page in Safari (Mac) or IE on Windows the side items are't cropped correctly.

If you scale the browser down and then click on the background and drag right you can reveal the cropped area of the page and it looks messy!

Is there a way around this? Or will I need to make do with the vertical scroll bar hiding?

Comment: You can use a media query to hide the images a a certain window width and remove the `min-width`. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Unfortunately the client doesn't want them hidden completely, just cropped. Otherwise that'd work great. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flex layout for this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvrXmG

- The `.container` element starts the flex layout.
- The `.img` elements have a `width` and `flex-basis` set to it and are not allowed to grow but to shrink, resulting in a "max-width".
- The `.wrap` elements have a `width` and `flex-basis` set to it and is not allowed to shrink but to grow, resulting in a "min-width".

If the page gets bigger the `.img` elements stay at the max size but the content acquires all free space.

if the page gets smaller, the content stays at its minimal width ant the image elements start to disappear.

This solution is probably not safe for old browsers but one of the easiest solutions for modern browsers [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and that's going to be great for my other projects. Unfortunately this is for education so I need to support IE8, certainly IE9. Otherwise this would've been ideal!